# How to set the correct URL for ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im creating a callback with ajax in a file called function.js in /js directory. the and the callback.php file is in the main directory. when I use "callback.php" in ajax's URL it work fine in my localhost, but when I transfer the files in web server, the server give me this error.

> status:404, status text: error

I tried with "/callback.php", "./callback.php", "public_hmtl/". but nothing works.

```
$.ajax({
    url :  "public_hmtl/callback.php", 
    data    : {
    func    : "deliveryOrderClient",
    clientId: clientId
    },
    type    : "post",
    error   : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("status:" + XMLHttpRequest.status + ", status text: " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
    },
    context :this,
    success : function(response){
        $(".resultCallBack").html(unescape(response));
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to see if the server are running PHP, and which is the root directory, when you run the file that call the function.js.

Comment: Im in 000webhost.com and PHP is runing. but about the root directory I don't have any idea.

Comment: `hmtl` is that right?

Comment: So what would the URL be in the browser to hit it directly as if it were a normal page?

Comment: If you put the callback.php in the same folder which run the index.php, so the url to call is just "callback.php"

Comment: typo, should be html not hmtl

Comment: are your JS folder and PHP were in the directory? like 'project folder > callback.php' & 'project folder > JS/function.js'?